# How to use vue-i18n with Vue class components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n, vue-class-components

The following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  public someText = this.$t('some.key')
}
```

Throws an error:

> `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: i18n is undefined"`

I made sure to initialize Vue with `Vue.use(VueI18n)` and `new Vue({ /* ... */, i18n })`. The `i18n` object is initialized this way:

```
new VueI18n({
  locale: DEFAULT_LOCALE, // imported
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages // imported
})
```

Translations work perfectly fine as long as they are not immediately called, for example in templates or in component methods.

This [vue-i18n issue](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/449) seems to imply that there is an initialization problem.
I could work around this by using methods and only translating in templates, but there is a specific instance out of my control in which such immediate calls happen: [Vuetify input](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs) `rules`.

```
someRule = [(v) => !!v || this.$t('field.must_not_be_empty')]
```

These rules are executed immediately, even with `lazy-validation` on [Vuetify forms](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms).

I have identified two possible solutions:

1. Circumventing the Vuetify `rules` system and allowing to simply return a string to be translated within the template itself;
2. Solving the `$t` immediate availability issue.

Sadly I have not been able to accomplish any of these.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue lied in the use of `this`.
Basically, Vue needs a very specific execution context that is not the same as what is normally accessible in the root context of a fresh `class`.

The solution ends up being very simple: Use a getter.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  public get someText () { return this.$t('some.key') }
}
```

Comment: is there any progress about this? How do you think did vue-class-component do smth about it?

Comment: @SashaKos The answer solves the problem. I'm thinking that the trouble with Vue class components is that while `$t` exists when the class is instantiated but it has not yet been populated with `i18n` (to which `$t` refers).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when defining rules for a v-text-field: `Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"`. Your solution with a getter doesn't seem to work for me: nameRules = [ (v: any) => !!v || this.errorName1]. Do you have any new input for this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you create it as a plugin? Mixin, component or what?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with placing the error message in a getter didn't work for me in the context of Vuetify input rules, I get this: `Error in beforeMount hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"`

I managed to get it working in 2 possible ways:

1. Use a getter, but for the whole rules array:

```
get someRules() {
    return [
        (v) => !!v || this.$t('field.must_not_be_empty')
    ];
}
```

2. Place the rules in the @Component decorator:

```
@Component({
    data() {
        return {
            someRules: [
                (v) => !!v || this.$t('field.must_not_be_empty')
            ]
        };
    }
})
export default class SomeComponent extends Vue {
...
}
```